# Are session variables persisted with Mule message on vm queues?

Tags: persistence, mule, messaging

I am using persistent vm queues for reliability within my Mule application. However I use a few session variables across the app that are needed in order for it to work.

My question is, are session vars persisted so they are available after a restart along with the message? Or should I use mule properties for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are. It is pretty easy to check what is persisted by setting some data and then looking at a file that Mule uses for file persistence. In Studio you can find them in workspace/.mule/.mule/myapp/queuestore/myvmpath/ directory.